# requirejs module alias/remap

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm currently integrating foreign code into our application.
Part of the process, I must substitute one of their requirejs modules with ours.

Obviously I can't modify their code, otherwise I'd have to do the change at every update. What I can do is modify the main.js (data-main of requirejs).

Here is, roughly, what they have:

```
requirejs.config({
    packages: [
        'beerpong'
    ]
});
```

So they have this `beerpong` package, with some modules in there. Among these modules, there is the `beer.js` file. It can be required with a `require('beerpong/beer')`.

Aside from this, I have my files, in a separate folder, say `vodkapong/beersubstitute`. What I would like is that, whenever someone `require('beerpong/beer')`, that requirejs actually serves him my `vodkapong/beersubstitute` instead.

**tl;dr: How can I remap an existing module to use my module instead?**

PS: Sadly, we're not actually writing a beerpong game... One day maybe!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use the [map option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map). It can remap an AMD module for a specific module or for all modules with the `"*"` name. An example would be:

```
require.config({
    map: {
        "*": {
            "beerpong/beer": "vodkapong/beersubstitute"
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery_ui_scrollbar: 'libs/jquery/jquery.custom-scrollbar'
    }
});
require(['dependency1', 'dependency2'], function (dep1, dep2) {
   // code goes here
});
```

And in your define call you can do this -

```
define(['jquery_ui_scrollbar'], function(scrollbar) {});
```